# set max time and min date datetimepicker vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

My datetimepicker **dtpDate** formatted **MM/dd/yyyy h tt**.

I want to set a minimum time and max time.

For example, minimum time is 9 AM and maximum time is 6 PM, when you select more than those, datetimepicker will prevent you from selecting time outside 9 AM - 6 PM.

Comment: do you want to limit the selection to just one day, or are you asking how to limit the time for *any* day?

Comment: Handle the `ValueChanged` event and perform your own validation.

Comment: @Plutonix yes, TIME for any day

Comment: the DTP will allow you to set a Min/Max DateTime for the control, but not a sub range within that.  Do as @CodyGray suggests and just validate the selection